# Play an Audio file with Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I want to play a small audio(residing on local machine or on any URL) clip when a dialog opens using JQuery. I am using ASP.NET and not HTML5. Is it possible to do so. I tried something like following but doesn't help. Any input on what am I missing or is it something that is not possible in traditional HTML?

```
playAudio = function () {
  console.log('start playAudio');
  var audio = document.createElement("audio");
  audio.src = "path/to/audio/here";
  audio.play();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use html `<audio>` tag try using the [HTMLAudioElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement) interface

```
var audio = new Audio('audio url'); 
audio.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that just with HTML:

```
<audio controls src="URI"></audio>
```

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOgNzr)